# How to extract picklist ids (as well as values) using Salesforce API?

Tags: php, api, soap, salesforce

I am building a system using PHP which interfaces with Salesforce by using the API to add bids/quotes onto Salesforce after they've been completed in the new system. For most fields this is fine however i'm trying to work out how to sync the picklists between the new systems. Whilst you can use the API to retrieve the values of the picklists from what I can see there's no way of obtaining the underlying ID for each picklist entry.

Ultimately I need to sync the picklist options between the two systems, this can be done by syncing the values but as soon as someone changes the value of the picklist field in Saleforce (or adds a new option) then this will no longer correspond with the picklist variables in the external system. Ideally if we could access the IDs then we can use the same ID/value list within the external system and (ideally) select the required picklist value based on the ID and not the value (which means even if the value has been changed slightly it will still correspond to the same entry). Similarly we can then easily check if any entries have been added/deleted so these can be added/deleted from the external system as well.

I can't find any reference as to how this can be done but I can't imagine we're the only ones wanting to do it? If this is not possible then how would one go about getting close to this using Salesforce, I presume it's possible in one way or another?

Cheers,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

the [describeSObjects](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/sforce_api_calls_describesobjects.htm) call returns metadata about objects & fields including picklist data, both values & labels, this should get you everything you need.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply that is massively appreciated. I can't actually see the values and labels within Salesforce itself, just one entry for each picklist entry,  i presume this is the label? Are the values calculated automatically (and in number format?) or are these created in another way and is there anyway to access these manually within Salesforce itself? Thanks so much!

Comment: unless you have translations enabled values & labels are the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but surely this means that the same problem will be true whichever you use and it still doesn't help in getting access to the index? Assuming this is the case do you know of anyway of accessing the actual index/key as detailed in the original question? thanks

Comment: the API does everything through the value string, its not really clear why that's not enough in this case.

Comment: Because the value string can be changed, so if this is updated in Salesforce then there's no way of mapping this to the external system and the lists would get out of sync. If the indexes/ids were visible then these could be used as these would never change (even if someone updated the related value string). Does this mean there is effectively no way of doing this or am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: If anyone knows if this is possible then i would love to hear your suggestions as I still find it very hard to believe that Salesforce doesn't allow proper integration with it's picklist values but that is what superfell seems to be saying

Comment: @deshg Hi, have you figured out this?